# Binding more than one <select> in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got a table of items, each with its own `<select>`. How do I bind these to the parameters of a controller method?

Ideally, I'd like an array containing (for each row in the table) the `value` of the selected `option`.

How do I do this? My google-fu is weak today.

Comment: How would you usually bind one <select>? Using a SelectList object? If so, why can't you just supply the view with one SelectList per row in your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your `<select>`s must have the same name plus [n], where n is zero based. Try this:

```
<% var i = 0; %>
<% foreach(var row in Model.Rows) { %>
<tr>
    <td>
        <%= Html.DropDownList(String.Format("options[{0}]", i++), row.Options as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) %>
    </td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

and your POST action could look like this:

```
public ActionResult YourAction(string[] options)
{
    ...
}
```